# Oracle CHECK Constraint on Two Date String Variants

Tags: regex, oracle, validation, date, check-constraints

I am working with a legacy Oracle database that has columns containing date strings formatted as follows:

```
30-Apr-03

30-Apr-2003
```

The column data type is `VARCHAR2(12)` (although `11` would suffice). Both of these representations can appear in a single column.

**Question:** How can I write a `CHECK` constraint that permits *only* these two date string variants in a column?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `CHECK` constraint to validate date strings of the form `19-Oct-12` or `19-Oct-2012`. In the case of date strings with a two-digit year, use a **RegEx** to prefix the year with `19` to avoid Oracle error `ORA-02436 - date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1
    MODIFY col_date1 CONSTRAINT col_date1_ck
        CHECK ((TO_DATE(
                 REGEXP_REPLACE(col_date1, '^(......-)(..)$', '\119\2'),
                 'DD-Mon-YYYY') > TO_DATE('31-Dec-1899')));
```

Longer term, if it is acceptable to make changes to the schema, using the [DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref151) data type (11g Release 2 (11.2)) would be more appropriate.

---

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately, this is not an effective solution. First, here is a situation where this `CHECK` constraint works as intended:

```
Value:  '05/Nov/12'
Result: ORA-02290: check constraint (TABLE1.COL_DATE1_CK) violated
```

However, this date string is accepted by the constraint:

```
Value:  '05/Nov/2012'
```

This is not wanted since the intent is to use `'-'` as the field separator, not `'/'`. Finally, consider this date string and its result:

```
Value:  '05/Foo/2012'
Result:  ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Here also, the constraint will not allow this value into the protected column. However, there is no indication in the resulting exception that this was a constraint violation. (What is wanted is `ORA-02290` as shown in the first example. But `TO_DATE()` is returning an exception instead of the `CHECK` constraint returning `False`.)

**Alternative:** For these reasons, I ultimately decided to solve this problem via a **trigger**. But I certainly welcome ideas on revising this `CHECK` constraint so that it truly accomplishes the objective.